# Webpack to build without including peer dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am building a React library and using Webpack to bundle it. I'm well aware of the concept behind dependencies and peer dependencies.

In the project, `React` is specified as a peer dependency.

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": ">= 16.3.0",
  "react-dom": ">= 16.3.0"
}
```

This is my `build` script

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js"
```

and this is my `webpack.config.babel.js`

```
import path from 'path';
import CleanWebpackPlugin from 'clean-webpack-plugin';
const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default () => ({
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    index: path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: packageJson.name,
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
  },

  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/*.*'])],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: 2
    }
  }
});
```

Every time I build, `React` code is included in the bundled file.
I'm unsure about how to bundle the library without including `React` in the bundled file.

Comment: Do you use `mode: 'production'` in your Webpack config both for an unminified and minified build because this way Webpack always applies tree-shaking?

Comment: Libraries don't need to be bundled. Their consumers will bundle them anyway. If you forego bundling your library, you'll automatically solve the `peerDependencies` problem.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I figured it out.

Webpack has a configuration called `externals`. Anything specified as an external will not be bundled together.

All I had to do was to add this config to `webpack.config.babel.js`

```
externals: {
  react: 'react',
  reactDOM: 'react-dom'
}
```

More info here - [webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

Comment: So this means Webpack bundles in even peer deps? strange behavior.

Comment: Webpack and package.json are two different pair of shoes. So yes, it needs to be included in Webpack's externals configuration.

Comment: What I've noticed is that I had to use 'styled-components': 'styled-components' rather than styledComponents: 'styled-components'