# Webpack - prevent font files (.woff, .eot, .ttf) in peer dependencies from being part of the build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to modify my webpack configuration such that font files (.woff, .woff2 .eot, .ttf) coming from **peer dependencies** won't be included in the build. Here's my Webpack config:

webpack.common.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"),
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets') }
      ],
    }),
  ],
  externals: {
    lodash: 'lodash',
    '@scoped/scoped-ui': '@scoped/scoped-ui',
    '@scoped/scoped-web-common': '@scoped/scoped-web-common',
    '@scoped/scoped-rich-text-editor': '@scoped/scoped-rich-text-editor',
    '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react': '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react',
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
    'react-bootstrap': 'react-bootstrap'
  },
  // also tried the array format
  // externals: ['lodash', '@scoped/scoped-ui', '@scoped/scoped-web-common', '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react', 'bootstrap', 'react-bootstrap'], 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
          {
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            options: {
              emitWarning: true,
              formatter: 'table',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'static/img',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: '/assets/'
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ttf-loader',
            options: {
              name: './font/[hash].[ext]',
              outputPath: '/assets/'
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Webpack (& related) version:

```
"webpack": "^4.44.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
"webpack-merge": "^5.1.3"
```

Peer dependencies in package.json:

```
 "peerDependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^2.1.0",
    "@scoped/scoped-rich-text-editor": "0.0.1-56",
    "@scoped/scoped-ui": "^1",
    "@scoped/scoped-web-common": "^1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "lodash": "4.17.21"
 },
```

The result of my build script is the following file structure:

```
    .
    ┠ dist
       ┠ assets
           ┠ [hashed].ttf
           ┠ [hashed].eot
           ┠ [hashed].woff
           ┠ [hashed].woff2
           ┠ [someImage].jpg
           ┠ [someOtherImage].png
       ┠ static
       ┠ index_bundle.js
       ┠ index_bundle.js.map
       ┠ index.html
```

Things I've tried:

1. Add an externals key to the webpack config as suggested in the following question: [Webpack to build without including peer dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53386748/webpack-to-build-without-including-peer-dependencies)
2. Try to exclude node_modules from the rules for the font files.
3. Remove the rules for the font files themselves.

Both 2) & 3) give me the same result, i.e build script fails with errors that look like the following:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/assets/fonts/418e7417-47f3-40a1-8817-519a566f9d82.eot 1:1
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/styles/font.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/styles/font.css) 4:0-101 33:73-102
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/styles/main.css
 @ ./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/styles/main.css
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ ./index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/assets/fonts/4cc8f5da-4e24-4929-8efb-866ffcb1fe7e.eot 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/styles/font.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/styles/font.css) 28:0-102 57:74-104
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/styles/main.css
 @ ./node_modules/@scoped/scoped-ui/build/styles/main.css
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ ./index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be solved by using a custom resolve plugin:

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

const PreventFontsFromPeerDeps = {
  apply (resolver) {
    const beforeFinalFile = resolver.getHook('before-final-file');
    
    let peerDepsFromMainRepo;
    beforeFinalFile.tap("PreventFontsFromPeerDeps", (request, resolveContext) => {
      if (!peerDepsFromMainRepo) {
        peerDepsFromMainRepo = request.descriptionFileData.peerDependencies;

        return;
      }

      const { path } = request;
      
      const isPathAFont = /* ... */;
      const isFromPeerDeps = Object.keys(peerDepsFromMainRepo).some(k => path.includes(`node_modules/${k}`));
      if (isFromPeerDeps && isPathAFont) {
        // By returning this, this request will be ignored.
        return { path: false };
      }
    });
  },
};

/**
 * @type {import("webpack/types").Configuration}
 */
const config = {
  /* ... */

  resolve: {
    plugins: [PreventFontsFromPeerDeps]
  },

  /* ... */
};

module.exports = config;
```

The part of the bundling process where this custom plugin intervenes can be thought of as the *resolving process*.
Here is where resources are resolved. This *resolving process* consists of multiple *stages*, such as: determining the `package.json`(also called description file) of the required module, determine whether the path refers to a path or to a directory etc.
These *stages* are internally represented as *hooks* in webpack's parlance. One of those hooks is `final-file`, which is responsible for determining whether the file exists or not. By using `before-final-file`, we're adding some sort of priority, meaning that our custom logic will run first.

The `peerDepsFromMainRepo` refers to the very first file that will be resolved. This file will most likely be part of the repo, so the `package.json` associated with it will be the one of the root directory, which means that we will be able to get the `peerDependencies` object from there.
The `request` object holds all the information we need, as we can see from this image:

[image]

What the plugin essentially does is to grab the peer dependencies from the `package.json` file of the project's root directory and then, for each incoming request(request = path to a resource), it checks whether that resource is part of the peer dependencies or not.

*Note: in the above image I took a simpler example, where I added `lodash` as a peer dependency. You can find the example [here](https://github.com/Andrei0872/understanding-webpack/tree/master/examples/peer-deps).*

---

I talked in a bit more detail about the *resolving process* in [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68565839/9632621)